# Order By on rails select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, sql-order-by

I have the following field in my form

```
 <%=f.select(:desk, @hotdesk.collect {|p| [ p.code, p.code ] }, {prompt: 'Select Desk Code...'})%>
```

It works fine but the order of desk codes are all listed in terms of ID. How can I list them in order of their code (alphabetical)?

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting `@hotdesk` in your controller?

Comment: Just with a single `@hotdesk = Hotdesk.all`

Comment: then you need to change that to `@hotdesk = Hotdesk.order(code: :asc)`

Comment: You should also consider writing a scope in your model, which would allow you to have something like `f.select(:desk, Hotdesk.for_select)`.

Comment: Just for clarity pette's solution works for rails 4 but for 3 you'd need Hotdesk.order("code asc") if you explicitly want to set the order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pette is surely about to say when you query to get hotdesk order by code

```
@hotdesk = Hotdesk.order(:code)
```

Comment: Of course it was that simple. I was too obsessed with putting something into the view. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You could specify `@hotdesk = Desk.order(code: :asc)` in your controller.
I am assuming `Desk` as your model name and `code` as your field. Replace them as per your model and field name.
If you want it in descending order then just specify `desc` instead of `asc`. By default ordering is ascending. So you can also do `@hotdesk = Desk.order(code)` for ascending order.

Comment: Thanks. It was that simple.